# QtLocation and QtPositioning not installed

Tags: kde, application-development, libraries, qml, qt5

I'm trying to develop a KDE widget that should display a map. At the moment I can't get the widget to load, because of the errors `module "QtLocation" is not installed` and `module "QtPositioning" is not installed`.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. Looking [at this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/), I've made sure that `libqt5positioning5` and `libqt5location5` are installed. The widget still does not load with the above errors.

[On reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/andotz/plasma_5_widget_development_qtlocation_and/) someone told me that I also need to install the QML bindings. What are the package names I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are talking about developing, in other words about programming, then you need to install development packages with headers:

- `qtlocation5-dev` for */usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtLocation/QtLocation*;
- `qtpositioning5-dev` for */usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/QtPositioning/QtPositioning*.

Install them along with QML bindings with

```
sudo apt install qtlocation5-dev qtpositioning5-dev 
sudo apt install qml-module-qtlocation qml-module-qtpositioning
```

Next time you can use the [file search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=QtPositioning&searchon=contents).

Comment: This didn't work: I still got the same error! I believe your answer is incomplete. As I'm using QML to develop the widget, your answer made me realize that the binding might not be under the `qt5` name. Indeed, [searching this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libs/) I found the packages `qml-module-qtlocation` and  `qml-module-qtpositioning`. After installing them, the widget started working. Please, if you could update your answer with these informations for future users, I will gladly accept it. Thank you! :)